# Upgrade with encrypted storage

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, encryption, cyanogenmod

I would like to upgrade my cyanogenmod to the latest M build. but my storage is encrypted, so i guess this will lead to some problems.

First of all i cant even seem to make a backup with CWM.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I upgrade from CM 10 to CM 11 with my storage being encrypted and make a backup before that.

Comment: I think you need to wipe the storage anyway to upgrade to a new major version. Perhaps someone more familiar with CM will answer definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClockworkMod Recovery (CWM) doesn't work with encrypted devices. You'll have to use TWRP: http://teamw.in/project/twrp2

Comment: strangely i cant flash twrp over my cwm. whatever i try i also find myself back in cwm.

Comment: What instructions are you following? Please post link.